# Shell Script: How to use cURL or wGet to call URL's from a list? I can get only the last row to work! Help! :)

Tags: shell, unix, curl, wget

Some help with Shell Script and cURL/wGet ?

I need to call multiple URL´s from a file.

While testing I´m using just 3 rows in that file, meaming that I have 3 URL´s.

Fist step I create the file and then I read it row by row calling via cURL or wGet using the block bellow:

```
cat ${vMyFile} | while read vMyRow #I cat the file and read it on a "While" structure
                 do
                 echo curl -f ${vMyRow} >>${vMyLogFile} #I use cURL to call the rows with the URL`s
```

The script works just fine, and the log file (vMyLogFile) shows me that everything worked.
The "curl" called all 3 URL´s with no erros BUT... I can only get the last row(URL) to work.

When I call these URL´s, a service is activated and only the server at line 3 (the last one) get activated. :(

If I get the cURL line 1 and 2 from the log file and run it thru terminal, the service is activated successfully.

I already tried to use SLEEP and WAIT between the cURL´s and still can´t get it to work properly.

Is there a "CLOSE" or "END" that I must user before calling a cURL request again in the same process?

Answer (score 0):

*I need to call multiple URL´s from a file.*

`wget` has option for such use case, namely `-i`. If not other options are specified it should be followed by name of file which holds one URL per line, so if this file is named for example `urls.txt` simplest usage is

```
wget -i urls.txt
```

If you want to know more about `-i` behavior consult [`wget`'s man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html).